# Can Salesforce Apps alter the default pages?

Tags: app

We are trying to figure out how our service/produce could possibly integrate with Salesforce via a Salesforce app.  I fully admit I am just learning Salesforce and I don't want to go down the wrong path in terms of design/planning.

Ideally, we'd want to integrate with the user's contextual workflow and not have them click on another tab when they want information from us.

Let's say I have some information that I want to show to a Chatter user - and I want them to access that information with a simple click of a button.  Can an app add a button to the default Chatter page?  Same goes with the Files tab?

Or, would the user/admin have to alter the page to add a button that would integrate with our service.  Or, is it not possible with an app at all - and we should do it within our VisualForce page?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  Yes.  You can create a Visualforce page and add it via the edit layout.

For example, if you want to add to the account page, you can create a Visualforce page like this:

......

And add it to the account page via "Edit Layout", and in the edit menu, scroll down to "Visualforce Pages" and drag it to where you like it.